# Outputting the results of a DataFrame to a QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyqt, qlabel

I have a Pandas DataFrame that outputs correctly in the Python console, however I'm creating an application using QT designer and would like this DataFrame to be output on a QLabel, the label is called:

```
<widget class="QLabel" name="LBL_RESULT">.
```

Do I need to use another widget type to display the DataFrame?

The code I have is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Identifier":id,"Description":desc})
print(df.to_string()) # prints everything to screen, not just the first page and last page.
df.to_csv('Test.txt',index=False) # saves the DataFrame to a text file
self.LBL_RESULT.setText(df)
```

The error is:

```
self.LBL_RESULT.setText(df)
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'DataFrame'
```

Please can you assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error points out, QLabel does not expect a dataframe but a string, so you must pass the result of `to_string()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Identifier":id,"Description":desc})
df.to_csv('Test.txt',index=False) # saves the DataFrame to a text file
self.LBL_RESULT.setText(df.to_string())
self.LBL_RESULT.adjustSize()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The quick response is much appreciated, this works perfectly. Thanks for explaining :)